# Open a new tab in the same dir as the previous

Tags: shell, zsh

Im using `zsh` and it seems that a new tab should open in the same dir as the previous. However, that is not happening.

Do I have to add anything to the `.zshrc`?

Comment: What is a "new tab" and what does it have to do with `zsh`?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with zsh.

`Konsole` and `gnome-terminal` do that: opening a new tab puts you in the same directory.
(Once upon a time, opening a new tab in gnome-terminal while reading a man page put you in /usr/share/man, maybe it has been fixed)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the "tabs" in a terminal emulator like gnome-terminal?
Understand that a new tab is nearly indistinguishable from a new terminal window. It runs a new instance of the shell which executes its start up files. The startup files do not know about any other shell instances, let alone what gnome-terminal they belong to or which current working directory that shell might be in. Another issue: with several open shells in different directories, which directory should the new shell start in?

That said, you could make each `cd` save the target directory in say `~/.cd` and change there in the startup file. Left as an exercise to the reader :-)

PS: Be sure to save the absolute path of the target directory, not some relative arg to `cd`.

Comment: This remembers last directory the user changed into, but not the directory that was open in the last terminal. For example, I could change into a directory in some terminal A, close it and some time later try to open a new terminal X while looking at terminal B. As as result I'll get the directory from the closed terminal A rather than from terminal B.